# Non-Square + Square = Other Square

Tags: number-theory

Let $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$

$a + b^2 = c^2$

$a$ is given.
How can I determinate b and c?

For example:

$8732 + b^2 = c^2$
$\Longrightarrow b = 22 \space \space and \space \space c = 96$

Because: $8732 + 22^2 = 96^2 \Longleftrightarrow 8732 + 484 = 9216$

Comment: $92^2\ne 8836$, $92^2\ne 9216$

Comment: You are right! Thanks, I fixed my volatility error :)

Comment: You won‘t find a solution if $a$ is an even number not divisible by $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a$ is odd, say $a=2n+1$, then choose $c=n+1$ and $b=n$.  If $a$ is even and divisible by $4$, that is $a=4n$, choose $c=n+1$ and $b=n-1$.

If $a$ is even but not divisible by $4$, then there's no solution: Given $a=2a'$ where $a'$ is odd, let $c=b+k$, thus
$$2a'=a=c^2-b^2=k(2b+k).$$
If $k$ is even, so is $2b+k$ and $a'$ would be even.  If $k$ is odd, so is $2k+b$ hence $2a'$ would be odd.

In your example $a=8732=4\cdot2183$, thus $8732=2184^2-2182^2$.

To minimize $b$ and $c$ determine a factorization of $a=a_1a_2$.  Then use
$$a=a_1a_2=\left(\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\right)^2-\left(\frac{a_1-a_2}{2}\right)^2.$$

Comment: It is possible to determinate a minimal $ b \in \mathbb{N} $ that $a + b^2 = c^2$?
For instance, in case of $a = 8732$ a minimal b is 24.

Comment: That's not what you were asking for. ;)

Comment: I will create a new question ;)

Comment: That task won't be that hard; you have to examine the prime factorisation of $a$, then use $a=k(2b+k)$.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

On re-arranging, we get

$$a = (c-b)(c+b)$$

So, now consider the set of factors of $a$. Given any factorisation of a as $a = pq$, we can find a pair of $(b,c)$, with

$b = \frac{p-q}{2}, c = \frac{p+q}{2}$

Comment: That doesn’t work for $a=6$.

Comment: For example: $8732 = 4 * 2183$ 

$b = \frac{2183 – 4}{2} = 1098.5 \notin \mathbb{N}$  

$c =  \frac{2183 + 4}{2} = 1093.5 \notin \mathbb{N}$

You are wrong!

Comment: @FishLike This provides a way for u to find solutions but it is not guaranteed that the solutions are integers. You have to try every possible factor pairs to get all integers solution

Comment: Ah okay! Thank you all, my friends :)

Comment: Now $6=1\cdot6=2\cdot3$.  Neither factorisation works: you are just wrong.

Comment: With $a=6$ which pair of squares are you expecting to get?

Comment: Just none: it's impossible.

Comment: So how am I wrong?

Comment: Let $a=6$.  Please show me natural numbers $b$ and $c$ such that $a+b^2=c^2$ -- you won't succeed

Comment: Right, so my method will also not give any integers that work