# Non-Square + Square (Minimal) = Other Square

Tags: number-theory

Let be $a,b,c \in \mathbb{N}$

$a$ is given. How can I determinate the **minimal** b?

$a + b^2 = c^2$

For example:
$8732 + b^2 = c^2 \Longrightarrow b = 22 \space \space and \space \space c = 96$

Please note, that I asked a similar question without the minimal b requirement.
(see: [Non-Square + Square = Other Square](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3744622/non-square-square-other-square/3744820?noredirect=1#comment7701362_3744820))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only a solution if $a$ is odd or divisible by $4$ (see below).

First let $a$ be odd. Find the factorization of $a=a_1a_2$, where $a_1$ is the smallest divisor of $a$ greater than $\sqrt{a}$; this isn't an integer since $a$ is not a square. Then set
$$c=\frac{a_1+a_2}{2}\quad\text{and}\quad b=\frac{a_1-a_2}{2}.$$

If $a$ is divisible by $4$ let $a=4a'$.  Now find the above mentioned factorisation of $a'$ instead of $a$.  Then set $c=a_1+a_2$ and $b=a_1-a_2$.

Example: $a=1120=4\cdot280$, thus $a'=280$ and $16<\sqrt{280}<17$, so $a_1'=20$ and $a_2=14$.  From here $c=34$ and $b=6$.

Comment: Can you give me an example with $a = 8732$ please? :)

Comment: If $a$ is divisible by $4$, it may be correct to pick $a-$ that *is* divisible by $4$. Rather, take for $a_1$ the smallest even divisor $>\sqrt a$ that is divisible by a lower power of $2$ than $a$ is.

Comment: @FishLike With $a=8732$, Michael's method leads to $a_1=118$, $a_2=74$, $c=96$, $b=22$.

Comment: Ahhhhh thanks!!

Comment: See my edit, please.

Comment: It is possible to solve my question without knowing the dividers of a? I am thinking about an equation system.

Comment: I don't think so.  See my revised answer, please.